# readYaml method is not available for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When I call `readYaml()` in jenkins pipeline I get an error that such method is not available.

```
def parameters = readYaml(file: "public/symfony/app/config/parameters.yml.dist")
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'readYaml' found among steps [...]
```

Jenkins version is 2.46.2.

I suspect the reason is Jenkins version and I need to upgrade to latest. Before I do that I would like to know if there is something else to try to solve this. I would prefer not upgrading since there are other important jobs that run there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to install the [pipeline utility steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps) plugin to use that function.

You can install it via the Jenkins plugin manager.

If you are running jenkins inside a container, you could also simply adjust the official image:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.46.2

RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh pipeline-utility-steps
```

Comment: You need at least Jenkins 2.73.2 for the [pipeline utility steps plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps)